# How to beautify HTML code without same directives breaking lines?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using Prettier for beautify my code on VS Code, but at some situations it is not look good for me for example;

This is how prettier beautifes with alt + shift + f

```
 <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-md-6">
                        <button
                            @click="hideButton"
                            class="btn btn-primary"
                        ></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is how I want:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-6">
            <button @click="hideButton"class="btn btn-primary"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I never want to see any "><" or same elements directives in different lines.

Which settings should I change? Or am I need to use another extension? I'm generally working with .vue files.